# how to write the equals() of Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to implement the equals method of Comparator, but stuck in halfway.
Regarding to the description in equals() that "sgn(comp1.compare(o1,o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2)) for every object reference o1 and o2." Should I take a case in this method? how can I know the every object reference o1 and o2 when I am writing the equals() .

```
      Comparator c = new Comparator<Interval>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Interval o1, Interval o2) {
            return o1.start - o2.start;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Type genericType = obj.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
            Type type = ((ParameterizedType) genericType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            if (((Class<?>) type).getName().equals(Interval.class.getName())) {
                // how to implement
                // "sgn(comp1.compare(o1,o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2))
                // for every object reference o1 and o2."
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why do you need your `Comparator` instance to be equal to something? And if you do override `equals()`, make sure you override `hashCode()` too.

Comment: Your .equals method should probably only mean "I *KNOW* this is equal". So, in the case of your Comparator, because its behavior does not rely on any member variables, anything of the same class is equal.

Comment: @Andy Turner  what you ask is another question I do not want discuss here, but you can see the description of equals() in Comparator "However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve performance by allowing programs to determine that two distinct comparators impose the same order."  It is not always needed to override hashCode() especially when I do not use it in any scenario of hash table

Comment: @Edward Peters equals() is used to compare this comparator with another comparator.  not 2 Interval  objects here.

Comment: @BruceZu Yeah, I'm aware of that. I'm saying that if a `Comparator` class has no member variables that influence its behavior, then any two instances of that class will satisfy the contract of `Comparator.equals`. (Also, read the wording carefully: `return false;` is a perfectly legal implementation of Comparator.equals. You don't need to perfectly identify every two equal comparators, you just need to not give false positives.)

Comment: @Edward Peters, it may be two instances of 2 anonymous sub class of Comparator, so it is still need to check "sgn(comp1.compare(o1,o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2))  for every object reference o1 and o2."  right?

Comment: @BruceZu No, because it doesn't have to be perfect. That's what I was pointing out: Nothing will break if your entire `equals` implementation reads `return false;`, or if you don't have one at all. Nothing will break because the compiler fails to recognize that two equivalent Comparators are equal; things could break if the compiler believed that two different Comparators were equal. Exhaustively testing all possible inputs to determine equality is not feasible.

Comment: Its obvious that you can't know whether any arbitrary comparator produces the same ordering as your own over an unbounded set, so that can't be your question. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @erickson that is just what i am asking, I also find the problem as your said "Its obvious that you can't know whether any arbitrary comparator produces the same ordering as your own over an unbounded set,"

Comment: @ Edward Peters I got your idea. it makes sense.

Comment: Instead of focusing on an obsolete `equals` implementation, you should focus on the correctness of the `compare` method. Since you never preclude negative numbers, returning `o1.start - o2.start` is broken as it can overflow, if the distance between these two points doesn’t fit into the `int` range. Use [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) instead of minus to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparators can be considered equivalent if they sort elements the same way. This test *could* be used to optimize sorting, but in practice I'm not aware of core Java collections taking advantage of this hint.

Failing to recognize this equivalence might eliminate some theoretical opportunities for optimization, but it won't break anything. So, it is generally not necessary to override the `equals()` method.

As the documentation for `Comparator.equals()` says:

> Note that it is *always* safe *not* to override `Object.equals(Object)`.

The default, identity-based implementation of `equals()` works well if you can define your order as a class or instance member, rather than creating a new instance each time it's used. This way, two sorted collections that use the same comparator can be detected, because their comparators will be equal.

```
private static final Comparator<Interval> orderByStart = new Comparator<Interval>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Interval o1, Interval o2) {
    return o1.start - o2.start;
  }    
};
```

---

> I see this is a work around

No. It's the correct way to implement the `Comparator.equals()` method.

Let's take a closer look at the solution you are insisting upon:

```
Comparator<Interval> c = new Comparator<Interval>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(Interval o1, Interval o2) {
    return o1.start - o2.start;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Comparator<?>))
      return false;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") /* We'll catch this below. */
    Comparator<Interval> that = (Comparator<Interval>) obj;
    return 
       IntStream.rangeClosed(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      .mapToObj(Interval::new)
      .allMatch(o1 -> {
         return
            IntStream.rangeClosed(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
           .mapToObj(Interval::new)
           .allMatch(o2 -> {
              int sig = Integer.signum(compare(o1, o2));
              try {
                return Integer.signum(that.compare(o1, o2)) == sig;
              } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                return false;
              }
            });
       });
  }

};
```

The `equals()` method of `Comparator` is meant as an optimization. If you can't test equality quickly and efficiently, don't bother trying—"it is *always* safe *not* to". The converse is *not* true: there is danger in implementing `equals()` incorrectly, as I've demonstrated here.

If you can't use a correct idiom, your program will look terrible and perform even worse.

Comment: I am using JDK 7, I copy your code to my IDE, find the code need JDK8.

Comment: I think your code works in my case.  while just like you said above "Its obvious that you can't know whether any arbitrary comparator produces the same ordering as your own over an unbounded set,"  when it is not to compare 2 integer, if it it is to compare 2 string. 2 members 'over an unbounded set', we can not override the equal(), is this the conclusion?

Comment: @BruceZu The conclusion is twofold: 1) You must not exhaustively test every possible pair of inputs in a `Comparator.equals()` implementation. That will be slower than whatever work you might have skipped if you knew the ordering is the same. 2) If you do override `equals()`, it should be based on a fast check, like testing if the other comparator is the same concrete class.

Comment: Thank you! 1) I agree with your rule "must not exhaustively test every possible pair of inputs", it is like what the method allMatch() said "May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result." however how could we know which pair we can skip? I think there are some cases it is hard to decide it.  E.g. if the comparator is to compare 2 strings, not int variables.  2) Yes, if they are instances of same concrete class it would be simple, while some times they are instances of 2 different anonymous subclasses of Comparator.